# Mildew or Mold?

Tags: mold

There was a roof leak in our art studio. In the past few weeks this has appeared. Does this seem like it can be cleaned (with mold killing methods seen online) and repainted or does the drywall need to be cut out and replaced?
[image]

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Even if the leak has been stopped, the drywall might still be soaked. Let it dry, then wipe those spots with diluted bleach and paint over them. That should take care of the issue. If the area remains dry, there's little risk of the mold reappearing.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can really, fully answer this is by digging in to the wall to check the condition of everything behind the surface. If it's all saturated behind there, you might have ongoing problems with mold even if you bleach and paint over the spot. There's a couple other approaches you can take though. One is to get a moisture meter - they aren't particularly expensive - and use that to measure the drywall to see just how saturated it is. The other is to YOLO it, bleach the spot, paint over it, and deal with it if and only if the problems come back. For any of these approaches you might want to run a dehumidifier in the space for a few days first to draw the moisture out of everything.